# Why is is to difficult to connect a frontend app to MetaMask?

Tags: metamask, dapps

I've been spending weeks trying to figure this out. I don't understand how you are supposed to connect your frontend app to metamask. What libraries are you supposed to use? How is it supposed to look like? And where the hell can I learn how to do this?

Comment: you dont connect your App (which is a Front End on its own) to another Front End which is MetaMask, you connect your App to the backend wich is an Ethereum node (like Infura). Metamask is only needed to generate a signature on the message (the transaction you are sending is the message)

Comment: Blockchain developers earn the average of $12,000 US dollars per month, so this salary  should be a good compensation for your frustration with getting things done

Comment: @Nulik ok, then explain to me how that backend is able to generate a request to sign trransaction using metamask or some other wallet ?

Comment: here is the docs, at the end there is a sample snippet https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#sign-typed-data-v4

Comment: the backend doesn't generate request to sign transaction, it is your App does that

Comment: @Vance The question's title reads more like a rant, if you have a specific problem it is better to ask directly.